# Pairwise count data from long format

Tags: r, count, transform

**Example data** 
I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c('X1','X1','X1','X1','X2','X2','X2','X2'),
  pos = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
  group = c(100,200,100,300,100,200,100,200)
)
```

Which thus looks like:

```
  id pos group
1 X1   1   100
2 X1   2   200
3 X1   3   100
4 X1   4   300
5 X2   1   100
6 X2   2   200
7 X2   3   100
8 X2   4   200
```

**What I try to achieve** 
I want to plot this data using `geom_segment()`, where `pos` will be on the x-xis,  and `group` on the y-axis. Then for each of these segments I want to count how often they are present in the dataset (based on the `id` column). When doing this for the example dataset the result would be:

```
pos1 pos2 group1 group2 id.count
1    2    100    200    2  
2    3    200    100    2  
3    4    100    300    1  
3    4    100    200    1
```

I have no clue how to start with this, while I'm familiar with `group_by` from dplyr I can not figure out how to build the initial four columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ordering in your data set is as in your example you can try this:

```
 library(dplyr)

 df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
        transmute(pos1 = pos, pos2 = lead(pos),
        group1 = group, group2 = lead(group)) %>%
        na.omit() %>% ungroup()%>%
        count(pos1, pos2, group1, group2, name = "id.count")
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#   pos1  pos2 group1 group2 id.count
#  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <int>
#     1     2    100    200        2
#     2     3    200    100        2
#     3     4    100    200        1
#     3     4    100    300        1
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following that works, but wonder if there is a more elegant solution for this:

```
# Simple stats
vals <- unique(df$pos)
min.val = min(vals)
max.val = max(vals)

# Combination
comb.df <- data.frame(
  pos1 = min.val:(max.val - 1),
  pos2 = (min.val + 1): max.val
)

# Combine
comb.df <- comb.df %>% 
  left_join(df %>% select(pos1 = pos, group1 = group, id )) %>%
  left_join(df %>% select(pos2 = pos, group2 = group, id ))

# Count
comb.df <- comb.df %>% 
  group_by(pos1, pos2, group1, group2) %>%
  summarise(n.ids = n_distinct(id))
```